# Eclipse quickfix import on cast?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have class "Map" which implements an interface "IOnlineMap".

When i try to cast my map class to IOnlineMap, and the import for IOnlineMap is missing in my import list, quickfix doesn't give the option to import. It only shows "Rename in file".

For example:

```
 ((IOnlineMap)map)
```

The entire "((IOnlineMap)map)" gets a red underline.

To add the import with quickfix i have to type:

```
IOnlineMap m;
```

and use quickfix to import IOnlineMap, next i remove "IOnlineMap m;", now the red line underneath "((IOnlineMap)map)" disappears.

Of course i can also manually add IOnlineMap to the imports, but I'm a bit lazy ;-)

Is there a trick in eclipse (mars) that will make the quickfix "Import" work for casts like ((IOnlineMap)map) or any other cast?

Comment: I can reproduce this in 4.5.1, but only when the resulting line is syntactically invalid even with the import

Comment: @JonK ((IOnlineMap)map) is indeed not syntactically valid, in this case there is no way (that i know) to generate the import (other then typing the import or going the IOnlineMap m; way like described). It can of course be that this is intended but it does bug me a bit with all the nice quick and handy features eclipse offers, cause casting is done quite frequently.